# Incompatible Shapes Error only when using Keras Sequential

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am an undergrad working on recreating the paper "Photo-Realistic Single Image Super-Resolution Using a Generative Adversarial Network" using TensorFlow. When attempting to test the network after training was completed, I get an error about incompatible shapes (Even though it worked for training). It seems this error is linked to Keras Sequential.

The end of the error gives:

```
File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [24,24,64] vs. [16,256,256,64] [Op:Mul] name: generator/sequential/p_re_lu/mul/
```

Where the training input shape is `(16,24,24,3)` and testing input shape is `(1,256,256,3)`. The first layers in the network is a `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 9, strides=1, padding='same'),` layer.

I separated some of the layers from the sequential and printed the output shapes as verification. The layers that I left in the sequential blocks throw the same error, while the separated ones work fine

output:

```
x_in: (16, 24, 24, 3)
x1: (16, 24, 24, 64)
x2a: (16, 24, 24, 64)
x2: (16, 24, 24, 64)
x3: (16, 24, 24, 64)
x4: (16, 48, 48, 256)
x5: (16, 96, 96, 256)
x_out: (16, 96, 96, 3)
x_in: (1, 256, 256, 3)
x1: (1, 256, 256, 64)
x2a: (1, 256, 256, 64)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "srgan.py", line 249, in <module> ...
```

Sequential block:

```
        self.residual = tf.keras.Sequential([
            Residual(cfg, num_filters),
            Residual(cfg, num_filters),
            Residual(cfg, num_filters),
            Residual(cfg, num_filters),
        ])
```

Call function

```
def call(self, x_in):

        print(f'x_in: {x_in.shape}')

        x1a = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 9, strides=1, padding='same')(x_in)
        x1 = tf.keras.layers.PReLU()(x1a)
        #x1 = self.start(x_in)
        print(f'x1: {x1.shape}')   
        x2a = Residual(self.cfg, 64)(x1) 
        print(f'x2a: {x2a.shape}')   
        x2 = self.residual(x1)
```

I'd expect the sequential to work the same as separated layers. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

edit1:
When I said I separated the layers, I mean moved the layers outside of the sequential.

I removed them all and tried the model again. The error is now for the `tf.keras.layers.PReLU()`, which makes sense since the error mentioned `name: generator/sequential/p_re_lu/mul/`

It is weird that this would be giving an error about compared shapes

Here is the model summary

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              multiple                  15616     
_________________________________________________________________
p_re_lu (PReLU)              multiple                  36864     
_________________________________________________________________
residual (Residual)          multiple                  111232    
_________________________________________________________________
residual_1 (Residual)        multiple                  111232    
_________________________________________________________________
residual_2 (Residual)        multiple                  111232    
_________________________________________________________________
residual_3 (Residual)        multiple                  111232    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            multiple                  331840    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_v2_8 (Ba multiple                  256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose (Conv2DTran multiple                  147712    
_________________________________________________________________
p_re_lu_5 (PReLU)            multiple                  589824    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr multiple                  590080    
_________________________________________________________________
p_re_lu_6 (PReLU)            multiple                  2359296   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           multiple                  6915      
=================================================================
Total params: 4,523,331
Trainable params: 4,522,179
Non-trainable params: 1,152
```

Comment: Not very clear from the info you posted. I do not get the separated layers. Could you show the model summary as well?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, you need to to reinitialize the model following. [Is loading in eager TensorFlow broken right now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55719047/is-loading-in-eager-tensorflow-broken-right-now)

There are a number of ways to do it, explained in the answer to the question in link above.