# I am trying to resume training from a certain checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I'm facing a problem with restoring training from the last checkpoint that I saved. I'm following exactly this code except that I'm changing the dataset and increasing the number of epochs to 100: [Machine Translation French-English notebook](https://github.com/syedshahzadraza/Encoder-Decoder-Model-with-Attention/blob/master/machine_translation_french_english.ipynb)

What do I add in order to keep the training because it wouldn't finish in one days and every time it re-starts from epoch 1.

I've found a similar question but the answer didn't solve the problem: [Resume training from a certain checkpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63205089/i-am-trying-to-resume-training-from-a-certain-checkpoint-tensorflow-because-i/72677710?noredirect=1#comment128377036_72677710).

Comment: You'd better put more concrete details about the problem you're facing, such as, Does `Checkpoint`  work? Any 'Exception' is thrown?

Comment: i solved the problem with using the checkpoint manager , you can find more details about it in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a very poor way to frame a question, kindly look into [how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to write a question in StackOverflow. 

To keep it short, research is lacking here, and the doubt is very open-ended. Plus, the question lacks a reproducible code example. Think of writing a question on StackOverflow like approaching a senior colleague for guidance during work.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late but I wanted to share the code of a possible solution to this.

Saving a checkpoint and restoring the model from it is pretty easy according to the Tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint#example_2). The saving can be done using the Tensorflow callbacks every epoch (or with a `save_freq` additional argument every x epochs):

```
model.compile(..., metrics=['accuracy'])
EPOCHS = 10
checkpoint_filepath = '/path/to/checkpoint'
model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_accuracy',
    mode='max',
    save_best_only=True  # if this is not the best epoch so far it is not saved.
)
model.fit(epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback])
```

Then, before starting a new train, or doing prediction, the weights of the saved checkpoint can be loaded like this:

```
model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
```

That's it.